# samba error "NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE" Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: server, samba

I have a brand new Ubuntu 22.04 server and I am attempting to connect to it from Ubuntu 22.04 desktop using Nautilus. Nautilus continues to prompt for user name and password but does not connect.
Using "smbclient -L localhost -U mless" on the server itself returns an error message "NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE"
There are no messages in the samba log files

#### Current Settings

##### `testparm` output

```
[global]
        client min protocol = NT1
        log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
        logging = file
        map to guest = Bad User
        max log size = 1000
        obey pam restrictions = Yes
        pam password change = Yes
        panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
        passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
        passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
        server min protocol = NT1
        server role = standalone server
        server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)
        unix password sync = Yes
        usershare allow guests = Yes
        usershare max shares = 0
        idmap config * : backend = tdb

[homes]
        comment = Home Directories
        create mask = 0700
        directory mask = 0700
```

##### Actual `smb.conf` file

```
[homes]
        browseable = yes
        create mask = 0700
        comment = Home Directories
        directory mask = 0700

[printers]
        browseable = No
        comment = All Printers
        create mask = 0700
        path = /var/spool/samba
        printable = Yes
        read only = Yes

[print$]
        comment = Printer Drivers
        path = /var/lib/samba/printers
        read only = Yes
```

##### `ufw status` output

```
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
10000/tcp                  ALLOW       Anywhere                  
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
Samba                      ALLOW       Anywhere                  
10000/tcp (v6)             ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
Samba (v6)                 ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

##### `smbclient -L localhost -U mick`

Comment: Did you add your user to the samba password database: `sudo smbpasswd -a mick`

Comment: Hi Morbius1 yes I have added my name to samba password - I have SAMBA so that Ubuntu users are also SAMBA users, Thanks for taking the time to help me

Answer (score 0):

Solution was set user password using sudo smbpasswd -a user
I don't know why converting linux users to smaba users didn't do this.

Why were 42 characters deleted??